# "In a week" or "a week"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

A book says:

> There are sixty minutes **in an hour.**
>
> There are twelve months **in a year.**
>
> There are seven days **a week.**

Where is the "in" in the third example, is "a year" an adverb here?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the "in"? It is missing. The word "year" is a noun.

Answer (score 2):

The **in** should be included:

> There are seven days **in** a week

in the same way as there are 12 months **in** a year.

We omit the preposition when we use constructions such as:

> He works seven days a week

an expression meaning every day of the week.

Similarly, we would say:

> You will find her ready to respond 24 hours a day

omitting the preposition - and NOT 24 hours in a day.

It depends on the context and what you're trying to say.

Units of time - seconds, minutes, hours, days - are nouns not adverbs.

Comment: In a motor bike, "Change the oil every in every 6000 KM" is written. Can I omit the "in"?

Comment: Yes, you must omit the **in**. It should read: **Change the oil every 6000 km**